# regular expression in password validation is not working?

Tags: java, android

In my Android project I have a regular expression and a string, in which I should have the matched expression. The problem is, I've only  not found?kindly see my code and whats my problem kindly classify it;

```
public void validatePassword(String gettext) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),gettext,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String regex ="((?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]) (?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#*=])(?=[\\S]+$).{5,10})";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile( regex ).matcher(gettext);
    if (matcher.find())
    {
        result = matcher.group(); 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Matches",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " No Matches",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

**The password contain one lowerCase(a-z),one upper Case(A-Z)character,one special Character,one numberic.it must contain minimum 8 and maximum 14 chAracters**

Comment: What's the problem? And what are you trying to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[@#*=]).{8,14}$
```

---

If you want to cover all special characters in ascii you can use

```
[!-/:-@\[-`{-~]
```

Comment: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: @user2773437 you need to escape \d to \\d